# Web Api ASP.NET no encuentra el metodo

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, postman

Al consumir con postman el API creado en asp.net me sale el siguiente error

```
{"Message": "No se ha encontrado ningún recurso HTTP que coincida con la URI de la solicitud 'http://localhost:9401/api/Usuarios/Login'.",
"MessageDetail": "No se encontró ninguna acción en el controlador 'Usuarios' que coincida con la solicitud."}
```

Aqui les dejo una captura del postman al momento de hacer la consulta
[image: Postman]

Aqui esta el codigo del metodo que hice en el api controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Login")]
public IHttpActionResult Login(string correo, string password)
{
    Hashtable Respuesta = new Hashtable();
    UsuariosBL Usuario = new UsuariosBL()
    {
        Email = correo,
        Password = password
    };
    UsuariosBL UsuarioResultado = Usuarios.Login(Usuario);
    if(UsuarioResultado.IDUsuario > 0)
    {
        Respuesta.Add("success", true);
        Respuesta.Add("usuario", UsuarioResultado);
        return Ok(Respuesta);
    }
    else
    {
        Respuesta.Add("success", false);
        Respuesta.Add("error", "El usuario o la contraseña son incorrectos");
        return Ok(Respuesta);
    }
}
```

Comment: UsuariosController

Comment: Probaste específicando `Route` ? --> `[Route("Usuarios/Login")]`

Comment: Ya lo probé y no funciona, por lo que veo si paso los valorespor url como si fuera get ya funciona pero no quiero mandarlos asi

Comment: Hola, establece el atributo `[FromBody]` en la definición de tu método. `public IHttpActionResult Login([FromBody] string correo, [FromBody] string password)`. De forma predeterminada, Web API  intenta obtener los tipos simples desde el URI de solicitud. El atributo `FromBody` indica a Web API que lea el valor desde el cuerpo de solicitud.

Comment: Me funciono el FromBody combinandolo con la respuesta de abajo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para acceder a las acciones del controlador, depende mucho de la configuración de las rutas. La generación por default es la siguiente en el archivo `App_start\WebApiConfig.cs`:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Dada esta configuración, basta con reemplazar  `{controller}`, por el nombre de tu controlador y `{action}` por el nombre de tu acción. En tu pregunta no mencionas el nombre del controlador pero dado el *screenshot* de Postman, debería ser `Usuarios` y tu acción se llama `Login`, quedando la url:

```
http://localhost:9401/api/Usuarios/Login
```

Si aún sigue teniendo el mismo problema, puedes declarar una ruta estática para acceder a la acción usando el atributo `Route`. La definición de la acción deberá quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Usuarios/Login")]
public IHttpActionResult Login(string correo, string password)
{
    // Código
}
```

Si deseas conocer más a fonde del funcionamiente del ruteo, acá está [la liga a la documentación oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1#attribute-routing).

---

## Actualización:

He notado un tema en el envío de tu petición y en la definición de tu API. Cuando esperas parámetros directamente en la acción (en este caso `correo` y `password`) el funcionamiento del Web API lo interpreta que lo espera directamente de la URL, es decir `http://localhost:9401/api/Usuarios/Login?correo=mail@mail.com&password=MiPassword`, es por eso que si lo envías por GET te va a funcionar.

La solución consiste en crear un modelo para usarlo directamente en la acción, y de esta manera el API tenga la posiblidad de leer el cuerpo de la petición y poder deserializarlo a un objeto.

Modelo:

```
public class LoginRequest
{
    public string Correo { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Código de la acción:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Usuarios/Login")]
public IHttpActionResult Login(LoginRequest loginRequest)
{
    // Código
}
```

Datos de la petición:

- URL: `http://localhost:9401/api/Usuarios/Login`
- Método: `POST`
- Headers:

  - Content-Type: Application/json
- Cuerpo de la petición (Body):

  ```
  {
      "Correo" : "mail@mail.com",
      "Password" : "MiPassword"
  }
  ```

Comment: Me funciono gracias solo le agregue el FromBody :)

Comment: Excelente, bien hecho :D

Answer (score 0):

Establece el atributo `[FromBody]` en la definición de tu método. Como ya te han comentado crea un modelo

```
public class LoginRequest
{
    public string Correo { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}    
public IHttpActionResult Login([FromBody] LoginRequest request)
```

De forma predeterminada, Web API intenta obtener los tipos simples desde el URI de solicitud. El atributo `FromBody`indica a Web API que lea el valor desde el cuerpo de solicitud.

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Login")]
public IHttpActionResult Login([FromBody] LoginRequest request)
{
    var correo = request.Correo;
    var password = request.Password;
    Hashtable Respuesta = new Hashtable();
    UsuariosBL Usuario = new UsuariosBL()
    {
        Email = correo,
        Password = password
    };
    UsuariosBL UsuarioResultado = Usuarios.Login(Usuario);
    if(UsuarioResultado.IDUsuario > 0)
    {
        Respuesta.Add("success", true);
        Respuesta.Add("usuario", UsuarioResultado);
        return Ok(Respuesta);
    }
    else
    {
        Respuesta.Add("success", false);
        Respuesta.Add("error", "El usuario o la contraseña son incorrectos");
        return Ok(Respuesta);
    }
}
```

Añado también la siguiente posibilidad de codificar el API

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Login")]
public IHttpActionResult Login(FormDataCollection form)
{
    var correo = form.Get("correo");
    var password = form.Get("password");

    Hashtable Respuesta = new Hashtable();
    UsuariosBL Usuario = new UsuariosBL()
    {
        Email = correo,
        Password = password
    };
    UsuariosBL UsuarioResultado = Usuarios.Login(Usuario);
    if(UsuarioResultado.IDUsuario > 0)
    {
        Respuesta.Add("success", true);
        Respuesta.Add("usuario", UsuarioResultado);
        return Ok(Respuesta);
    }
    else
    {
        Respuesta.Add("success", false);
        Respuesta.Add("error", "El usuario o la contraseña son incorrectos");
        return Ok(Respuesta);
    }
}
```